# Is there a fastclick library (or other solution) in Dart to remove the 300ms delay (ghostclick) on mobile devices?

Tags: android-layout, mobile, touch, dart, touch-event

My app is less responsive on mobile devices. It seems that many (all?) browsers put a [300ms delay](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) to decide if the touch was a simple or double touch.

There are solutions for this, like [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), but I'm wondering if there is one using Dart code ?

EDIT: There is a method `preventGhostClick` in: [ClickBuster.dart](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/samples/ui_lib/touch/ClickBuster.dart?r=11726), anyone has ever tried this method? Example?

Comment: Have you considered using js-interop?

Comment: Yes. I was looking for a 100% Dart solution (ready to use).  So far, there is none and do-it-yourself or js-interop with fastclick seem the only ways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The delay is independent of any browser, JavaScript or library like Dart. It's the way Android detects a double click just by waiting after the first tap if there will be a second one.

In the lower level API of Android you can react on touch-down and touch-up events directly. You could implement this using plain java (e.g. as Android Service), but I've no idea how to call that or listen to its touch-events using Dart.

Comment: While it's not the information I was looking for (I suppose the answer to my question is just -no-), but thanks for the Android info, the bounty is yours.

Comment: Yep. I thought it's better to give you one way that is at least possible instead of leaving you alone with the 'no'. Can you share with how you're solving this issue now?

Comment: For now it's just few lines using the onTouchStart subscription.  I will eventually try [this logic](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) in Dart code.